# Vue： How can I get the true array instead of [__ob__: Observer] arrays?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue, and want to get my data from the database with an API call:

```
  data() {
      return {
        total: 0,
        liblist: []    
      }
  }

  created() {
      this.getLibList();
  },

  methods: {
      async getLibList() {
      const { data:res } = await this.$http.get('/api/user/select_all_info');
      this.liblist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
      console.log(res);
      console.log(this.liblist);

    }
  }
```

Here I want to access the array from my API and then assign the array to `liblist:[]`.

I even tried to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))` to convert data type.

But sadly I got this result from console like this:

Here is console result of 'res':

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "1111", em: "111111", pw: "7"}
1: {id: "12121212", em: "4144@gmail.com", pw: "6666"}
2: {id: "121213333", em: "admin333", pw: "333"}
3: {id: "2222", em: "2222", pw: "2"}
4: {id: "444444", em: "4444", pw: "444"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But when it turns to 'liblist',it returns:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
2: {__ob__: Observer}
3: {__ob__: Observer}
4: {__ob__: Observer}
length: 5
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(5), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

I really cannot understand: why after `this.liblist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))`the data become 'observer' type ??

In that case I cannot see any data in my table-componet:
[my page's display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFLRM.png)

P.S. Here's my frontend code:

```
<el-table stripe max-height="500" :data="liblist">
<el-table-column label="Account" prop="id"></el-table-column>
<el-table-column label="Email" prop="em"></el-table-column>
<el-table-column label="Password" prop="pw"></el-table-column>
```

So what's wrong with my code? Please help me.

Comment: Hi ,Try to remove  additional stringify use like this this.liblist = JSON.parse(res);

Comment: What does your api returns?
Why are you using stringify and parse?

Comment: All that `Observer` stuff is just Vue's reactivity system and it is nothing to worry about. As soon as you assign the array to the `data` property `liblist` Vue will walk through the array and the objects within it and rewrite them to be reactive. The properties should still retain their original values. Try adding `console.log(this.liblist[0].id)` immediately after your other logging.